# Change background cell in tableView permanently after selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I change the background cell permanently after being selected? What I know is by using `cell.selectedBackgroundView` it will only change the cell background for a while and then it goes back to normal.

I want it to change permanently when selected even after app are closed. I tried to search for a solution but could not find relevant answer.

this is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

//set up selected cell background
        cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_selected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_selected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];

        }

        //set up cell
        CGFloat nRed= 0/255.0;
        CGFloat nGreen=73.0/255.0;
        CGFloat nBlue=144.0/255.0;
        UIColor *myColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:nRed green:nGreen blue:nBlue alpha:1];

//set up cell text
        cell.textLabel.text = [[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:15];
        cell.textLabel.textColor=myColor;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 0.2 alpha: 1.0];

        //set icon image for cell
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:
                              [[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"icon"]];

        return cell;
    }
```

below are my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    indexPath];
    [self->tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if ([[[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"action"] isEqualToString:@"a1"]){

        NSString *title_a1 =[[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *content_a1 = [[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"content"];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        // saving an NSString
        [defaults setObject:title_a1 forKey:@"title_a1"];
        [defaults setObject:content_a1 forKey:@"content_a1"];

        WebBrowserViewController *webview=[[WebBrowserViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebBrowserViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self presentModalViewController:webview animated:YES];

    }else  if ([[[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"action"] isEqualToString:@"a2"]){

        NSString *title_a2 =[[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *content_a2 = [[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"content"];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        // saving an NSString
        [defaults setObject:title_a2 forKey:@"title_a2"];
        [defaults setObject:content_a2 forKey:@"content_a2"];

        WebBrowserViewController *webview=[[WebBrowserViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebBrowserViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self presentModalViewController:webview animated:YES];

    }else {

        NSLog(@" other action key get! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to make a permanent change you need to have some sort of flag for your data that is being displayed in that cell. Lets say you are displaying user information in each cell, in that case you need to have set the users object flag to the Yes and when you close the app you should save that data to the plist or somewhere based on your storing mechanism. When you launch your app next time, while you are creating your cells you will check that flag and change the cell color accordignly. Hope helots.

Comment: @lionserdar..thanx for the idea..can u give an example in detail for me? sorry to asking in deep because i'm newbie in ios..can i use NSUserDefaults to save that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one property to your datasource array, for example, named  `BOOL isSelected`. 
in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you update `isSelected = YES`. and add the following

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

to update the selected cell. and in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

```
if(data.isSelected){
   cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_selected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
 }
```

the code is here:

You need add one bool property to the object in your array. For example,you add

`@property (nonatomic)  BOOL isSelected;` to your object class's header file.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

//set up selected cell background
        //cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_selected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
        //cell.selectedBackgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_selected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];

        }

        if (((YourObjectType *)[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).isSelected){
            cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_selected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
        } else {
             cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_selected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];

        }

        //set up cell
        CGFloat nRed= 0/255.0;
        CGFloat nGreen=73.0/255.0;
        CGFloat nBlue=144.0/255.0;
        UIColor *myColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:nRed green:nGreen blue:nBlue alpha:1];

//set up cell text
        cell.textLabel.text = [[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:15];
        cell.textLabel.textColor=myColor;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 0.2 alpha: 1.0];

        //set icon image for cell
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:
                              [[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"icon"]];

        return cell;
    }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    indexPath];
    [self->tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    ((YourObjectType *)[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).isSelected = YES;

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [tableView endUpdates];

    if ([[[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"action"] isEqualToString:@"a1"]){

        NSString *title_a1 =[[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *content_a1 = [[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"content"];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        // saving an NSString
        [defaults setObject:title_a1 forKey:@"title_a1"];
        [defaults setObject:content_a1 forKey:@"content_a1"];

        WebBrowserViewController *webview=[[WebBrowserViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebBrowserViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self presentModalViewController:webview animated:YES];

    }else  if ([[[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"action"] isEqualToString:@"a2"]){

        NSString *title_a2 =[[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *content_a2 = [[AryStoreknowItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"content"];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        // saving an NSString
        [defaults setObject:title_a2 forKey:@"title_a2"];
        [defaults setObject:content_a2 forKey:@"content_a2"];

        WebBrowserViewController *webview=[[WebBrowserViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebBrowserViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self presentModalViewController:webview animated:YES];

    }else {

        NSLog(@" other action key get! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx Chancy..seem like the right answer for me..let me try first and i'll accept the answer later after i tried

Comment: @user2767343 you need any help just ask.

Comment: Chancy..sorry to interrupt u again..i really new in iOS and i really stuck to code that..can u show me in detail where to put that code?I've provide my code in question above..see my edit question..thanx again and really appreciate if u could help..

Comment: @user2767343 where is your datasource array? and you should put the CellIdentifier to your  [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil] instead of nil.

Comment: @user2767343 if you don't use array, you can make one array of BOOL value, init all to NO, the count is the same with - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
method returned. and then you can update the one which is selected to YES in didSelect method. and access the values in the cellFor method to detect and set the value

Comment: Chancy, my array is AryStoreknowItem..how can i set this array to BOOL?

Comment: @user2767343 i update the code in my answer. you need add one property to the object in you array.

Comment: chancy, i think this might work..one more last question, what u mean by YourObjectType?anyway thank you so much..u help me a lot.

Comment: @user2767343 i mean the object type in your array.